# High-precision coordinates issue with boost::voronoi

Tags: c++, boost, voronoi

While experimenting with [`voronoi_advanced_tutorial.cpp`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/polygon/example/voronoi_advanced_tutorial.cpp) higher-precision coordinates I've noticed that one of my output diagrams exhibits a math error (apparently). The diagram does not exhibit such errors, however, with the default coordinates (`int` input and `double` output).

### Default int and double coordinate system.

The following figure shows the output diagram primary edges (orange) for a set of input edges (black). Everything looks fine.
[image]

### High-precision coordinate system.

Once I change to `boost::int64_t` input and `long double` output the diagram exhibits some errors. From what I could find out, it is related to the internal-right rectangular shape. Only the internal-left and the outer rectangle works. Once I insert the right one, however, it fails.
[image]

I can't figure what is causing the issue and the `int_type` to `ftp_type` conversion seems correct. I've also shifted the polygon shapes far from coordinates with 0 - i.e. `(0,0)` -> `(100,100)` - but the problem persisted (it was visually "better" at least). Any suggestions on what to look for with this issue?

You can find the [Full Code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KBsn375ftetmmP8C) available through Wandbox. I've tried GCC 11.1.0, 10.2.0, and 9.3.0 with boost 1.75.0 and 1.77.0.

**EDIT:** On the *high-precision coordinate system* figures the 4th is a zoom from the 1st configuration (i.e. the outer rectangle and two inner rectangles). I've used the purple arrow to try indicating such "zoom". In practice I've removed those points that *exploded*, thus rendering unreadable the 1st figure.

Comment: If you have code that can reproduce this simply by changing precision, then it's clearly library bug, and you should file a bug report. If you suspect issue is in your own code, or want to make it more likely to get help here, first try to create a [mcve] and add it to the question.

Comment: @hyde disagree: _"The coordinate data type is a template parameter of all data types and algorithms provided by the library, and is expected to be integral. Floating point coordinate data types are not supported by the algorithms implemented in the library due to the fact that the achieving floating point robustness implies a different set of algorithms and generally platform specific assumptions about floating point representations. "_ - https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/polygon/doc/index.htm

Comment: @sehe: [voronoi builder](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/polygon/doc/voronoi_builder.htm) documentation states that "*The requirements for the coordinate type of the input/output geometries, (...), are the following: - The input coordinate type (...) is not required to be integral (while it still should be an integer type); - The output coordinate type (for Voronoi vertices) is **required to be IEEE-754 floating point type**.* Their default is an `int` input and `double` output, and the code I'm using is from their tutorial database.

Comment: Oh yeah. I didn't look to closely at the examples, but if the input is integral that seem it should have been fine. Reading a little closer it does seem that you're using a different approach for the my_voronoi_diagram_traits/my_voronoi_ctype_traits as well.

Comment: Is there a source of authority to rule out issues in the traits/FP converter/ulp_comparsion? E.g. a link to accompanying tests.

Comment: What does the purple arrow indicate? I get your first-pane result, but the fourth-pane when using -ffast-math. How did you get those images?

Comment: @sehe: I've added the missing explanation for the **purple arrow**.

Comment: I'm using the code from boost advanced tutorial, changing only the input (and some flavor). All `my_(..)_traits` and conversions comes from boost tutorial. There could be a issue in them, but I could not spot it. My first guess was that my inputs were wrong, but it works for the default types.